# How to use preloadedState in Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to save changes in state even if the page is reloaded. I've checked my oldState const in console.log and it works. But my ui doesn't show state from local storage. How can I use my oldState const in preloadedState?

```
const saveState = state => {
  try {
    const serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state)
    window.localStorage.setItem('appState', serialisedState)
  } catch (err) {
    // error message
  }
}

const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serialisedState = window.localStorage.getItem('appState')
    console.log(serialisedState)
    if (!serialisedState) return undefined
  } catch (err) {
    // error message
    return undefined
  }
}

const oldState = loadState()

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products,
    filters,
    product,
    cart,
  },
  preloadedState: oldState,
})

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState())
})
```

Comment: What did you get? And what result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

In your `loadState` after this line

```
if (!serialisedState) return undefined
```

you should have return the value

```
return serialisedState
```

Updated `loadState`:

```
const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serialisedState = window.localStorage.getItem('appState')
    console.log(serialisedState)
    if (!serialisedState) return undefined
    return serialisedState
  } catch (err) {
    // error message
    return undefined
  }
}
```

Hope that will help.